What does begingroup/endgroup actually do?
I've started to notice that all my MetaPost/MetaFun figures are surrounded by
begingroup ;

endgroup ;

Probably because I put that here when I wrote my snippet... But the fact is, I never actually learned what these two actually do.
So... what are the meanings of begingroup and endgroup in MetaFont/MetaPost/MetaFun?

There is some explanation available in the MetaPost user manual (texdoc metapost) section 10.1 "Grouping".

If you want to understand grouping, you should probably start with Chapter 15 of The MetafontBook (CTAN has the source code for it).   I can't repeat all of that in this answer, but here is a my attempt at a summary.
In MF/MP begingroup and endgroup are used to enclose a list of statements.  They bind the enclosed list into a syntactical unit, just like parentheses are used in maths to give structure to an algebraic expression.
In programming MF/MP these groups have two useful functions:

groups can be used to "protect the values of variables in one part of the program from being clobbered in another"

a group can also be used as part of an algebraic expression so that MF/MP can "do arbitrarily complicated things while in the middle of other calculations".


Protecting variable values
Unlike many other programming languages (e.g. Python) all variables in MF/MP have global scope in your program unless you specifically protect them.  So any macro you define can make changes to any other variable in your program.  This can be useful, but often leads to confusing code.
So if you are writing a macro that is more than a couple of lines long, it is a good idea to surround it with a begingroup, endgroup pair and save the names of your local variables at the start of your definition.
 def useful_macro(expr a, b, c) = 
     begingroup;
     save p, q;  pair p; boolean q;
     ... do useful stuff with parameters a, b, c 
     ... and local variables p and q
     ... and so on... 
     endgroup;
 enddef;

Now the values that you assign to your local variables p and q inside your group will vanish at the end of the group, and any values that those symbolic tokens had before the group will be restored.   This pattern is so useful, that there is a short-hand version of it built in:
 vardef useful_macro(expr a, b, c) = 
     save p, q;  pair p; boolean q;
     ... your macro content ... 
 enddef;

Yes, that's right, vardef adds an automatic grouping pair at the start and end of your definition.   Note again that every variable is global unless you explicitly save it.  When you do save it, then for the duration of your group it loses any value and any type that it had before.  So unless you want to use it as a <numeric> you will need to re-declare it inside the group, as shown in my example.
(Note that if the variable to want to protect is an "internal quantity" like ahangle or ahlength, then you should protect it with interim instead of save, and there is no need to re-declare it).
Using a group as an expression
Groups fit into MF/MP's expression syntax like this:
begingroup; <statement list>; expression endgroup;

where expression can evaluate to a <numeric>, <pair>, <string>, <picture>, etc.  So what MF/MP does with a group expression is: Perform the list of statements, then evaluate the expression, then restore anything that was saved in the group.  The value of the group expression is then the final expression evaluated.
This means that there is no explicit return command (as in Python) to force the return of a particular value, the value of the group is simply the last expression evaluated.
Note also that this means that you should not (normally) put a ; between the final expression and the endgroup.  Can you see why?
An example
As an example consider the thelabel macro from plain.mp (slightly simplified):
vardef thelabel@#(expr s, z) = 
  save p; picture p;
  p = s if string s: infont defaultfont scaled defaultscale fi;
  p shifted (z + ... stuff to deal with offsets ... )
enddef;

Recall that vardef automatically surrounds the macro with begingroup and endgroup.   So the first line makes p a local picture variable.  Then the value of s is assigned to p (and converted to a picture if needed), then the final expression is the local <picture> p shifted to <pair> z (plus some stuff to deal with alignment and offset).  This final expression is "returned" as the value of the group, and the local value of p is forgotten.
